# What is the argument of a real number?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the argument of a real number? In my book they say $\arg(\sqrt{3}+i) = \dfrac{\pi}{6}$ and we were working with complex numbers. What does this mean?

Comment: The argument of a positive real number is zero. Could it be a typo for $\arg(\sqrt{3}+i)$?

Comment: @stewbasic Yes, I think you are right.

Comment: The argument is the angle for the complex number (subject to things like branch cuts).

Comment: So do you still mean to ask what the argument of a _real_ number is? Or of any number?

Comment: If argument is the angle, a real number, x + 0i, has angle of 0.

Answer (score 2):

The argument of a complex number, represented in polar form as
$$
z=re^{it}
$$
is $t$ 
plus or minus some multiple of $2\pi$. You can think of it as the angle the position vector of the complex number makes with the real axis.

Comment: +1. The other piece, $r$, is the absolute value (maybe after fixing a minus sign).

Comment: In other words, the angular displacement from the x-axis counter-clockwise in an Argand diagram